# boost::variant visitor return error (most vexing parse?)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, boost-variant

I have an `std::array` of `boost::variant` object, and I'm trying to create a `boost::static_visitor` which visits an element in the array, returning a reference to something in each of the variant member types. That's a mouthful, so here's a code snippet mimicking my implementation:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <array>

struct SomeType {};

struct A {
  SomeType something;
  SomeType& someMethod() { return something; }
};

struct B {
  SomeType something;
  SomeType& someMethod() { return something; }
};

struct C {
  SomeType something;
  SomeType& someMethod() { return something; }
};

typedef boost::variant<A, B, C> MyVariant;

class SomeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<> {
public:
  template<typename T>
  SomeType& operator()(T& operand) const {
    return operand.someMethod();
  }
};

class MyVariants {
public:
  SomeType* getSomething(unsigned index);

private:
  static const size_t count = 100;
  std::array<MyVariant, count> variants_;
};

SomeType* MyVariants::getSomething(unsigned index) {
  if(index < count) {
    MyVariant& variant = variants_[index];
    SomeType& something = boost::apply_visitor(SomeVisitor(), variant);
    return &something;
  }
  else {
    return nullptr;
  }
}
```

This snippet compiles with clang 3.6.2, but gcc 5.3.1 spits out the following (followed by a few dozen errors from the boost variant headers)

```
test.cpp:43:47: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'SomeType&' from an rvalue of type 'boost::static_visitor<>::result_type {aka void}'
     SomeType& something = boost::apply_visitor(SomeVisitor(), variant);
```

All the errors seem to say the same thing - the visitor's return type is `void`, and I can't bind that to a `SomeType&`. I don't think there are any syntax errors with my implementation of `SomeVisitor` since this compiles fine with clang.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617810/boost-variant-apply-visitor-compilation-error) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737826/why-cant-i-visit-this-custom-type-with-boostvariant) show similar errors generated by a `boost::static_visitor`, and both were explained by C++'s most-vexing-parse. In both those questions, the issue was something like this (using types from my snippet above):

```
MyVariant variant(A());
SomeType& something = boost::apply_visitor(SomeVisitor(), variant);
```

In this context, I can understand how the most vexing parse applies. `MyVariant variant(A());` might be ambiguous to the compiler. I don't know how this applies to my snippet though, since `MyVariant& variant = variants_[index]` seems pretty explicit. I don't know if these questions are even related to my issues.

Any advice/help would be appreciated

Comment: You have to specify the return type in static_visitor's template argument list. Leaving it empty is telling the compiler that the functor will return void.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly the problem. I made a `boost::static_visitor` with a return value a few weeks ago (with the right syntax) so I'm doubly embarrassed

Comment: We've all done it. Note that in later versions of boost with c++14 you don't need a static visitor. A lambda with `auto&` argument type will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment provided as an answer:

You have to specify the return type in static_visitor's template argument list. Leaving it empty is telling the compiler that the functor will return void.

```
class SomeVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<SomeType&> {
public:
  template<typename T>
  SomeType& operator()(T& operand) const {
    return operand.someMethod();
  }
};
```

Alternatively, in later versions of boost with c++14:

```
auto& something = boost::apply_visitor([](auto& x) { return x.someMethod(); }, 
                                       variant);
```